# Synchronizing webpage and local pdf

Tags: programming-languages, html, text-processing

I would like to solve the following problem. On my website, I have a list of my publications. I also have my list of publications on a latex file of my cv. The issue is that I update these manually, and it becomes tedious and error-prone to keep both in sync. I am considering writing a program that will automate the process of syncing.

In my mind, I imagine having a single text file with the raw data of the publications. The program then should

1. format this data so it fits the format of my cv and then has latex create a pdf using this data.
2. format this data so its fits the format of my website and then adds it to the HTML code in the right way.

I can handle the string manipulation needed to format. It is less clear to me how to instruct the program to add the strings to the tex file in the right place and then compile it, and also how to add the strings to the html file in the right place. Advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are looking for a macro processing tool/language that can then be used to write the html and latex files from a common template and data source. One example of this is [gnu m4](http://www.gnu.org/software/m4/) (there are many others out there). (I'd have to sit down and work on writing a proper answer for this - not something I can build / test / explain on my current system).

Comment: For one resume, updated less than once per day, you may wish to consider [Is it worth the time?](https://xkcd.com/1205/).  Doing the automation would likely have rewards of its own (learning, removing potential errors), but saving time isn't one of them.

Comment: @Dan: Certainly the one resume might not be worth the time. But the acquired skills and code are likely to be transferable.

Comment: @MichaelT: Thanks. I'll look into gnu m4.

Comment: The acquired skills definitely have value and should probably be mentioned on the resume somewhere.

Comment: @Dan: that's funny. Unfortunately it's still unclear to me how to proceed. Any advice?